# <<-sql in Ruby to get a relation?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So I have a function like this:

```
def get_relation(my_offset, my_limit):
  query = <<-SQL
        SELECT *
        FROM my_table
        Limit my_limit <--- HERE
        Offset my_offset <--- HERE
        Order by id
  SQL
  // How can I return a relation here with model MyTable?
```

So I am wondering two things:

1. How can I use my variables `my_limit` and `my_offset` inside the `<<-sql`? Is my syntax to include those correct?
2. How can I run this raw query and get a relation out of it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with my answer proposed [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69679579/rails-relation-ordering) since this appears to be the same question. I would be happy to update my answer but you keep hiding pertinent details like model names.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [Rails query language](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) instead of manually building a string with a SQL statement. The following line is identical to your SQL statement and returns an ActiveRecord Relation.

```
MyModel.limit(my_limit).offset(my_offset).order(:id)
```

Comment: I am trying to get a CTE thats why I must have a raw query I thought?

Comment: perhaps I should have added it in the question. The ultimate goal is to a relation which has these results:


```

With my_table_sub_table as {
Select *
From my_table
Limit 50
Offset 100
Order by id
}
...
```

Is there any way to do this?